# Flying your own trips part 91 if your jet is on a part 135 certificate

Tags: part-91-operations

If an individual owns a business jet and places it in an LLC, then in turn places it on a part 135 operator’s certificate, can that individual fly his own trips under part 91?

Comment: It's relatively common to see a fractional/charter flight strip (EJA, XSR, LXJ, etc) with the remarks "PART 91 FLIGHT" or "PART 135 FLIGHT." That doesn't change the way I handle the flight as ATC, but it shows that it is possible to operate the same aircraft under different flight rules. Also sometimes you'll see a flight that would normally be "EJA123" be flown as "N123QS" instead, which I imagine is another indicator of 91 instead of 135.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

FAA operating certificates are applicable to revenue generating flight activity, but there are many reasons besides personal use where an aircraft may be operated under part 91, including flight to a maintenance facility, post maintenance check flights, repositioning for logistical reasons, etc.

Comment: I recently had an off-the-record conversation with a highly respected aviation tax attorney about the tax advantages of having your jet on a part 135 certificate. One specific question I asked him was how it affects the tax situation if an owner elects to fly his/her own personal or business flights under part 91. His answer caught me by surprise… He said that unless the aircraft is owned directly by that individual, not by an LLC or other business entity, which almost all business jets are, the aircraft in question cannot be operated under part 91 by the owner. Where is that in the regs?

Comment: That sounds like a good question for a "highly respected aviation tax attorney", which I am not.  I am taking my best guess based on some part time work for a 135 operator where we would fly occasional flights under part 91.  I don't know how that may have been affected under different ownership arrangements, and I will delete this answer if it turns out to be wrong...

Comment: P.S.  I meant no snark at all in the comment above, just that you should probably seek professional advice for what you are seeking to do.  There may be tax implications outside of the CFRs governing part 135 and 91 operations that will influence your direction.  My point is, *to my knowledge* there is nothing in the CFRs that directly prohibit this.  The key would be to write it into your operating manual that the FAA reviews and approves.  If it is in there and approved, you would be good to go.